# sequelize update record primary key value

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to update the id value of an existing instance using Sequelize but it is not being persisted to the DB

```
// model definition
var User = sequelize.define('users', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    unique: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    field: 'id'
  }
)};

// usage
User.findById(oldId).then(function(user) {
 user.id = 'new value';
 user.save(); // Id remains the same in DB
});
```

I'm using sequelize 3.14.0 with node and a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Have you considered separating that field to something else and treating the primary key as static?  My gut feeling is that primary keys are assumed to not change by most ORMs.

Comment: You should print the error to see what is going on,
user.save().catch(function(err) { 
  console.log(err)
});

Comment: For me, it doesn't throw an error and fails silently :(

Answer (score 6):

As others have hinted in the comments, sequelize won't let you update the primary key, see https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/f482790b85ef2336bb97893c0eaa127d9d6bbc77/lib/instance.js#L334-L336

Answer (score 0):

I've opened an issue for this:
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5827